# How can I compare strings the user has entered in?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to compare user input from `READ` with a string, like so:

```
CL-USER 36 > (equalp (read) "same")
same
NIL
```

However, as you can see, even though I type in "same," `EQUALP` says my input and the string are different. How can I compare these two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`read-line`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_lin.htm) for this:

```
CL-USER> (equalp (read-line) "same")
same
T
```

`read` would return a symbol:

```
CL-USER> (type-of (read))
same
SYMBOL
```

From the [Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_rd.htm):

> read parses the printed representation of an object from input-stream
>   and builds such an object.

You just want to read a string, whereas `read` *parses* the input and constructs Lisp objects from it.

To get strings out of `read`, you'd have to use the "printed representation" of strings, i.e. put them in double quotes:

```
CL-USER> (equalp (read) "same")
"same"
T
```

(BTW: There is `string=` for string comparisons; `equalp` will ignore case.)